# EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash on didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: xcode, swift, crash, exc-bad-access

My application suddenly started crashing and after four hours I still can't figure out why. It worked perfectly last Friday and I haven't changed anything to the code since.

I have tried:

- Stepping through code with breakpoints.
- Adding an Exception Breakpoint.
- Enabling Zombie objects.
- Turning static analyser on.

None of these made me any wiser or pointed me to a more exact error message.

The crash happens when I select a cell. It then points to the AppDelegate with the message "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS". Continueing the program execution does not give a more clear error message.

Some images of the error and my code can be seen below. I am really at a loss here so any help will be much appreciated.

[image: AppDelegate]
[image: Hierarchy]
Code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    var dealer : DealerList
    var alldealer : TotalDealerList
    var id : String

        if scAll.selectedSegmentIndex == 0
        {
            if scMatur.selectedSegmentIndex == 0
            {
                if (self.resultSearchController.active)
                {
                    dealer = filtereddealers[indexPath.row]
                }
                else
                {
                    dealer = dealers[indexPath.row]
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (self.resultSearchController.active)
                {
                    dealer = filtereddealers[indexPath.row]
                }
                else
                {
                    dealer = sorteddealers[indexPath.row]
                }
            }

                //Create a message box with actions for the user.
                let actionSheetController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "What to do with:", message: "'\(dealer.dlName)'?", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

                let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { action -> Void in
                    //Just dismiss the action sheet
            }

                //starts a phonecall to the selected dealer
                let callAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Call", style: .Default) { action -> Void in
                    var phonenr = "0634563859"
                    let alert2 = UIAlertController(title: "Please confirm", message: "Call '\(dealer.dlName)' at \(phonenr)?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                    alert2.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
                    alert2.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { UIAlertAction in

                        self.callNumber(phonenr)
                        })

                    self.presentViewController(alert2, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

                //action that opens the DealCustView. Pass data from this view to the next. ID is used in the next view.
                let showcustomersAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Customers", style: .Default) { action -> Void in
                    let reportview = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("dealcustList") as! DealCustView
                    reportview.id2 = dealer.dlSCode
                    reportview.sourceid = self.id
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(reportview, animated: true)
            }

                //add the actions to the messagebox
                actionSheetController.addAction(cancelAction)
                actionSheetController.addAction(showcustomersAction)
                actionSheetController.addAction(callAction)

                //present the messagebox
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    self.presentViewController(actionSheetController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                })
        }
        else
        {
            if scMatur.selectedSegmentIndex == 0
            {
                if (self.resultSearchController.active)
                {
                    alldealer = filteredalldealers[indexPath.row]
                }
                else
                {
                    alldealer = alldealers[indexPath.row]
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (self.resultSearchController.active)
                {
                    alldealer = filteredalldealers[indexPath.row]
                }
                else
                {
                    alldealer = sortedalldealers[indexPath.row]
                }
            }
                ///
                //Create a message box with actions for the user.
                let actionSheetController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "What to do with:", message: "'\(alldealer.tdlName)'?", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
                let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { action -> Void in
                    //Just dismiss the action sheet
            }

                //starts a phonecall to the selected dealer
                let callAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Call", style: .Default) { action -> Void in
                    var phonenr = "0634563859"
                    let alert2 = UIAlertController(title: "Please confirm", message: "Call '\(alldealer.tdlName)' at \(phonenr)?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                    alert2.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
                    alert2.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { UIAlertAction in

                        self.callNumber(phonenr)
                        })

                    self.presentViewController(alert2, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

                //action that opens the DealCustView. Pass data from this view to the next. ID is used in the next view.
                let showcustomersAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Customers", style: .Default) { action -> Void in
                    let reportview = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("dealcustList") as! DealCustView
                    reportview.id2 = alldealer.tdlSCode
                    reportview.sourceid = self.id
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(reportview, animated: true)
            }

                //add the actions to the messagebox
                actionSheetController.addAction(cancelAction)
                actionSheetController.addAction(showcustomersAction)
                actionSheetController.addAction(callAction)

                //present the messagebox
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    self.presentViewController(actionSheetController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: show your crash log from console.

Comment: show your cell for row and other delegates

Comment: I would use the breakpoint navigator to set an exception breakpoint.  That should stop on the bad line instead of jut telling you which method had the error.